# matrix that forms an orthogonal basis with a given vector

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, linear-algebra

A linear algebra question;

Given a k-variate normed vector u (i.e. u : ||u||_2=1)
how do you construct \Gamma_u, any arbitrary k*(k-1)
matrix of unit vectors such that (u,\Gamma_u) forms an
 orthogonal basis ?

I mean: from a computationnal stand point of view: 
what algorithm do you use to construct such matrices ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive approach would be to apply Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation of u_0, and k-1 randomly generated vectors.  If at some point the GS algorithm generates a zero vector, then you have a linear dependency in which case choose the vector randomly again.

However this method is unstable,  small numerical errors in the representation of the vectors gets magnified.  However there exists a stable modification of this algorithm:

Let `a_1 = u,  a_2,...a_k` be randomly chosen vectors

```
for i = 1 to k do 
        vi = ai
end for 

for i = 1 to k do
    rii = |vi| 
    qi = vi/rii
    for j = i + 1 to k do
       rij =<qi,vj>
       vj =vj −rij*qi 
    end for
end for
```

The resulting vectors `v1,...vk` will be the columns of your matrix, with `v1 = u`.  If at some point `vj` becomes zero choose a new vector `aj` and start again.  Note that the probability of this happening is negligible if the vectors a2,..,ak are chosen randomly.

Comment: Thank you: i go back home and try it and let you know,

Best.

Comment: Instead of starting with a random base, you could. 1) Check if the starting vector is a multiple of one in the canonical base. 2) if it is, select the other n-1 vectors in the canonical base. 3) If it is not, check any n-1 vectors of the caninical base. /// No probability of choosing a wrong base.

Comment: @belisarius,  you could still end up with linear dependence.  Consider the trivial case u = (1,1,0),  and e1=(1,0,0), e2=(0,1,0), e3=(0,0,1), then u is not a linear multiple of any one but choosing e1 and e2 as the other two vectors would result in a linear combination.   In general detecting linear combinations is not cheap, so its probably cheaper to just restart the Gram-schmidt method with a new random vector since this is such a rare event

Comment: @user189035: I don't think so, what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Householder matrices to do this. See for
example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_reflection
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

One can find a Householder matrix `Q` so that `Q*u = e_1`
(where `e_k` is the vector that's all 0s apart from a 1 in the k-th place)
Then if `f_k = Q*e_k`, the `f_k` form an orthogonal basis and `f_1 = u`.
(Since `Q*Q = I`, and Q is orthogonal.)

All this talk of matrices might make it seem that the routine
would be expensive, but this is not so. For example this C function,
given a vector of length 1 returns an array with the required basis 
in column order, ie the j'th component of the i'th vector is held in b[j+dim*i]

```
   double*  make_basis( int dim, const double* v)
{
    double* B = calloc( dim*dim, sizeof * B);
    double* h = calloc( dim, sizeof *h);
    double  f, s, d;
    int i, j;

    /* compute Householder vector and factor */
    memcpy( h, v, dim*sizeof *h);
    s = ( v[0] > 0.0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
    h[0] += s;  
    f = s/(s+v[0]);

    /* compute basis */
    memcpy( B, v, dim * sizeof *v); /* first one is v */
    /* others by applying Householder matrix */
    for( i=1; i<dim; ++i)
    {   d = f*h[i];
        for( j=0; j<dim; ++j)
        {   B[dim*i+j] = (i==j) - d*h[j];
        }
    }
    free( h);
    return B;
}
```