# Trouble creating an orthonormal matrix with given vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Similar problem to this question [matrix that forms an orthogonal basis with a given vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140068/matrix-that-forms-an-orthogonal-basis-with-a-given-vector#) but I'm having problems with my implementation. I have a given vector, `u`, and I want to construct an arbitrary orthonormal matrix `V` such that `V(:,1) = u/norm(u)`. The problem I'm getting is that `V'*V` isn't `I` (but is diagonal). Here's my code:

```
function V = rand_orth(u)
    n = length(u);
    V = [u/norm(u) rand(n,n-1)];

    for i = 1:n
        vi = V(:,i);
        rii = norm(vi);
        qi = vi/rii;
        for j = i+1:n
            rij = dot(qi,V(:,j));
            V(:,j) = V(:,j) - rij*qi;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply normalize columns of `V` once you've finished the orthogonalization. Note there's also no need to normalize `u` (first column) initially, since we will normalize the whole matrix at the end:

```
function V = rand_orth(u)
    n = length(u);
    V = [u, rand(n,n-1)];

    for i = 1:n
        vi = V(:,i);
        rii = norm(vi);
        qi = vi/rii;
        for j = i+1:n
            rij = dot(qi,V(:,j));
            V(:,j) = V(:,j) - rij*qi;
        end
    end

    V = bsxfun(@rdivide, V, sqrt(diag(V'*V))');
end
```